Use `StaticRenderer` subclass to render a sequence of matrices in python asciimatics library
background
I am trying implement a subclass of StaticRenderer that can render a 2d matrix of random characters over a set duration, similar to how gifs can be looped using renderers.ColourImageFile(StaticRenderer).
I want to use this subclass as the renderer argument of the Print(Effect) class' instantiator, similar to this example.
code
This is what I have implemented so far (i am setting the matrix to be the height and width of the terminal):
from asciimatics.screen import ManagedScreen, Screen
from asciimatics.scene import Scene
from asciimatics.effects import Print
from asciimatics.renderers import StaticRenderer
from asciimatics.exceptions import ResizeScreenError

import random
import time
import sys


class RandomMatrixRenderer(StaticRenderer):
    def __init__(self, screen: Screen):
        super(RandomMatrixRenderer, self).__init__()
        self._width = screen.width
        self._height = screen.height
        self._matrix = self._generate_random_matrix()
        self._screen = screen

    def _generate_random_matrix(self):
        chars = "!@#$%^&*()_+=-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        matrix = [
            [random.choice(chars) for _ in range(self._width)]
            for _ in range(self._height)
        ]
        return matrix

    def render_now(self):
        for y in range(self._height):
            for x in range(self._width):
                self._screen.print_at(
                    self._matrix[y][x],
                    x,
                    y,
                    colour=random.randint(0, 7),
                    bg=random.randint(0, 7),
                )


def random_matrix(screen):
    while True:
        effect = Print(screen, x=0, y=0, renderer=RandomMatrixRenderer(screen))
        screen.play([Scene([effect])], repeat=False)
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Wait for 1 second before showing the next matrix


def main():
    with ManagedScreen() as screen:
        random_matrix(screen)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            main()
            sys.exit(0)
        except ResizeScreenError:
            pass


problem
However, I am encountering this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marcu/resources/tutorials/asciimatics/waves/matrix_render.py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/marcu/resources/tutorials/asciimatics/waves/matrix_render.py", line 49, in main
    random_matrix(screen)
  File "/home/marcu/resources/tutorials/asciimatics/waves/matrix_render.py", line 43, in random_matrix
    screen.play([Scene([effect])], repeat=False)
  File "/home/marcu/resources/tutorials/asciimatics/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asciimatics/screen.py", line 1602, in play
    self.draw_next_frame(repeat=repeat)
  File "/home/marcu/resources/tutorials/asciimatics/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asciimatics/screen.py", line 1705, in draw_next_frame
    effect.update(self._frame)
  File "/home/marcu/resources/tutorials/asciimatics/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asciimatics/effects.py", line 63, in update
    self._update(frame_no)
  File "/home/marcu/resources/tutorials/asciimatics/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asciimatics/effects.py", line 334, in _update
    image, colours = self._renderer.rendered_text
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/marcu/resources/tutorials/asciimatics/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/asciimatics/renderers/base.py", line 165, in rendered_text
    return (self._plain_images[index],
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Does this have to do with the parameters stop_frame and speed in the Effect class? Or is there an issue with my matrix input?
